# After extruding the face where i extruded from is missing

Tags: extrude

this is probably something simple so i'll explain in short :

after extruding , if a delete this face(pic 1)

[image]

you can clearly see that the face where i extruded from disappeared(pic 2)

but i want that both faces stay there , undeleted 
[image]

basically i want to have both picture 1 face and picture 3 face when extruding
but instead i get 1 and 2 .

Thanks in advance .

Note : i used to do this 2 years ago (i can tell because i've loaded some of my models from 2014) but i can't remember how i did .

Comment: in edge select mode, alt+E, then edges only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and type "extrude only edges". 
Or in edge select mode hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and choose "only Edges"
This way it keeps the original face in place and extrudes the edges only.

If you want to select multiple faces, you have to switch to edge select mode and only select the outer rim of the faces. 

[image]

Hit only <kbd>E</kbd> and extrude the edges:
[image]

Comment: i guess that's one way but what if i extrude more than one face ? It would be a pain in the *** to create new faces to all those new edges .

Comment: updated the answer, does it now solve your problem?

Comment: i mean if you have a curvy mesh (eg a cylinder) and try to create new faces with the F key the fresh edges after edge extrude they won't fill correctly

Comment: Why do you want to fuse faces, using the F key? actually im not hundred percent sure if i have understand your initial question, maybe you want to update your main question post. Eg what are you even trying to achieve in the long run? Also maybe you should try the Loop Tools addon, maybe it provides you with a better solution for your problem. https://vimeo.com/21459725

Comment: an other solution would be this https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-121984.html and just remove doubles after i'm done however it's still not the way i used to extrude but anyway i'll use both this method and yours depending on the situation

Comment: i'm trying to have both faces in pic 1 and pic 3 when i extrude , your solution shows how to achieve pic 3 and by creating new faces pic 1 will be achieved as well but this won't work on multiple faces

Comment: ah now i understand. The loop tool's function called "bridge" can merge multiple faces. you should give it a try.

Comment: Helpful add-on , thanks a lot for the recommendation .